# jQuery X-editable update dropdowns

Tags: jquery, select, dropdown, x-editable

I would like to edit each element of a dropdown (select) using x-editable.

```
<div style="margin: 150px">
  <select id="list1">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
  </select>
</div>

$('#list1').editable({
  success: function(response, newValue) {
    console.log("response: "+response+' val: '+newValue);
  }
});
```

It seems that x-editable merge all the options in a string. When is selected an option, x-editable displays all them. Here newValue = "test1   test2".

[image]

Is there a way that x-editable is able to edit each option in a select ?

=> [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/frankv2100/xBB5x)

Thx!

Comment: Do you maybe mean that you want to replace the options with the new one you are getting in the response

Comment: Yes.. but it seems that x-editable is not working with selects

Comment: There are a few ways to do that. If you are getting the values from a database then I need to see what your response looks like. If you instead want to add the options to the dropdown list manually then the markup will be different.

Answer (score 0):

First you need anyway a server side script to save the edited values.

```
your_saving_script.php
```

If you are setting the values manually then you can do:

```
$('#list1').editable('http://www.example.com/your_saving_script.php', {
     data   : " {'1':'Test 1','2':'Test 2', 'selected':'1'}",
     type   : 'select',
     submit : 'OK'
 });
```

If you are getting the data from server-side you need a script to fetch your data:

```
your_json.php
```

**Server-side script**

```
<?php
 /* http://www.example.com/your_json.php */
 // fetch data from database and return the values in the array
 $array['1'] =  'Test 1';
 $array['2'] =  'Test 2';
 $array['selected'] =  '1';
 echo json_encode($array);
 ?>
```

And:

```
$('#list1').editable('http://www.example.com/your_saving_script.php', {
     loadurl : 'http://www.example.com/your_json.php',
     type   : 'select',
     submit : 'OK'
 });
```